# How to count agent entering and exiting a node

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent 'Pallet' that will be seized by an agent 'Operator' and flows through each process through seize --> moveTo --> delay--> release blocks. **How can I count the number of agents(Pallet) in each rectangular node?**

The pallet will be seized by 'Operator' to the individual nodes and delay for a few minutes before moving to the next process by seizing and releasing.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDO4Z.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcDMZ.png)

[Properties of Process A's rectangular node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCgT5.png)

[Seize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnsNA.png)

[MoveTo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFYHO.png)

[Delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJsBb.png)

[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31M0o.png)

Tried using variable with +1 when enters and -1 when exit however, it counted the agent 'Operator' instead of Pallet.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that if your agents are transporters or pedestrians. Default agents cannot be "taught" to realize when they enter a node (easily), see the [help](https://anylogic.help/markup/node-r-mhl.html#accessing-agents-in-the-node):
[image]

3 options:

1. Use transporters and their "on enter/exit node" code boxes
2. Give your normal agents recurring events where they manually check all the time if they entered a node (hard, also computationally costly)
3. Switch to a fully agent-based networking setup (advanced technique, see this Youtube series: https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiGJP0k1miFbQ0XfchiMK9nxj-qr42dyw )

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify if I were to use the first option, the transporters are only for the "Pallet" and the other agent "Operato" still remain as the normal agents?

Comment: Anything that enters/exits your nodes needs to become transporters...

Comment: Is there a way I can bypass the simulation of the 1-hour duration limitation? My simulation does not require more than 1 hour but it indicated that I ran for more than 1 hr.

Comment: Please always open new issues for new questions, StackOverflow does not work like a forum, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow 

Also, if a reply was helpful, please upvote it, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote